# Whatsapp Notification does not display contact name

Tags: iphone, ios, upgrade, preview, notifications

The problem I’m experiencing is that contact names do not appear on whatsapp notifications (locked and unlocked). For example, if I get a message from Dad, whatsapp only displays the whatsapp logo and “message”, without displaying the sender. When I turn on message previews, I can see both the contact name and the message preview, but I used to be able to see just the contact name (“Dad has sent you a message”) instead of having to see the preview. This just happened as I updated to ios 11.3.1. I reached out to whatsapp and they mentioned below:

To turn on previews that display the contact name but not message:
Go to WhatsApp > Settings > Notifications > turn Show Preview on.
Go to iPhone Settings > Notifications > WhatsApp > Show Previews > Never

I made the above changes and now when i get notification it reads (Dad-Notification and NOT “Dad has sent you a message”)
Anyone having a similar problem? Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [Basic Customer Support](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y) question. Please see the meta post link for details on how to proceed if you can edit the post and, if put on Hold, have the Hold reviewed.  You can also contact the software developer for assistance with their product.